# How do I handle the Git error "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git

Particularly the .DS_Store file, I'm on a mac so I of course put this in my .gitignore. I don't care about the file at all. But for some reason it is trying to pull it from the bare repo I setup as a server.

```
   Updating 8e11f79..b315527
    error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .DS_Store
        config/wi-fi.txt
        web/.DS_Store
    Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
    Aborting
```

Comment: Putting the .DS_Store in the gitignore file is not enough if it is already versioned.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the option. And for wi-fi.txt you have to resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you got the error due to a pull, the damage has already been done: Someone has already committed a `.DS_Store` file to `git`. This should never happen, of course, but it has happened.

You really don't want such files to be under version control, because

1. `git` will modify them when it checks out a commit, or, even worse, it will actively merge changes from someone else into a local `.DS_Store` when you merge a branch possibly creating a broken `.DS_Store` file. I have no idea what your OS does with the contents of these files, but it's not expecting you to change them in any way.
2. You will get an error whenever you try to checkout a revision containing a `.DS_Store` file when your OS has modified it.
3. Non-Apple users won't like the `.DS_Store` files littering your repository.

I would advise you to try to hunt down the origin of the file, because that information is central for how you can fix the issue. The command

```
git log --all -- .DS_Store
```

gives you a list of all the commits that have touched the `.DS_Store` file. These are the commits that you need to rewrite to remove the `.DS_Store` from your history.

Rewriting the commits can, of course, be done with the big gun `git filter-branch`, but as long as it's only recent commits that have not been merged yet, you can get away with doing a `git rebase -i`.

And, of course, when you are done, put `.DS_Store` in your `.gitignore` *and check it in*. This should stop people from (accidentally) adding `.DS_Store` files in the future.

Comment: This error occurs even if `.DS_Store` is staged locally (not necessarily pushed to repository). Unstaging the `.DS_Store` solves the issues as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63365285/3337089)

Answer (score 8):

Not a silver bullet, but the following worked for me:

```
git restore --staged ../.DS_Store
```

Answer (score 3):

find . -name .DS_Store -print0 | xargs -0 git rm -f --ignore-unmatch

Answer (score 1):

Just remove **.DS_Store** :)

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is necessary to check and delete `.DS_Store` file, if it is exists.

I also had this error when there is no such file.

Adding `.DS_Store` line into `.gitignore` helped to solve this problem.

Answer (score -2):

After you committed and pushed your changes, can try

```
git reset --hard
```

Don't forget to add **.DS_Store** to **.gitignore**